# OSMDroid - how to set two tile source?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I trying to implement OSM using osmdroid, so far i am able to do everything correctly. But i would like to know how i can set two tile sources on top of each other.

Below is how i am trying to implement :

```
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.getTileProvider().getTileCache().getProtectedTileComputers().clear();
        map.getTileProvider().getTileCache().setAutoEnsureCapacity(false);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        map.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("USGS Topo", 0, 18, 256, ".png?apikey=123",
                new String[] { "https://api.xyz.com/maps/satellite/zxy/2020-04-21T16:10:00Z/" }) {
            @Override
            public String getTileURLString(long pMapTileIndex) {
                return getBaseUrl()
                        + MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)
                        + "/" + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)
                        + "/" + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)
                        + mImageFilenameEnding;
            }
        });
        map.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
```

So far i am getting below output but there is no mapnik source under the satellite tile source.

[image]

but i need the output to look like this

[image]

How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [wiki docs on osmdroid's GitHub page](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources#can-i-use-more-than-one-tile-source-at-a-time), you can use more than one tile source at a time.

You can only set one `setTileSource`, so for your code to work you need to set the map as the tile source and add the weather tile layer as an overlay over it.

```
     map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
     map.getTileProvider().getTileCache().getProtectedTileComputers().clear();
     map.getTileProvider().getTileCache().setAutoEnsureCapacity(false);
     map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

     MapTileProviderBasic provider = new MapTileProviderBasic(MainActivity.this, new OnlineTileSourceBase("USGS Topo", 0, 18, 256, "png?apikey=123", new String[0]) {
        @Override
        public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
            // BoundingBox bbox = tile2boundingBox(aTile.getX(), aTile.getY(), aTile.getZoomLevel());
            // String baseUrl ="https://api.xyz.com/maps/satellite/zxy/2020-04-21T16:10:00Z/?dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png24&bbox="+bbox.west+","+bbox.south+","+bbox.east+","+bbox.north+"&size=256,256&f=image";
            return "https://api.xyz.com/maps/satellite/zxy/2020-04-21T16:10:00Z/" + aTile.getZoomLevel() + "/" + aTile.getY() + "/" + aTile.getX();
            // return baseUrl;
        }
    });

    TilesOverlay layer = new TilesOverlay(provider, MainActivity.this);
    layer.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    layer.setLoadingLineColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    map.getOverlays().add(layer);

    map.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
```

If you are using osmndroid-wms then too you can use a map layer and an overlay layer on it by changing the following line

```
  MapTileProviderBasic provider = new MapTileProviderBasic(MainActivity.this, mWMSTileSource)
```

over here `mWMSTileSource` will be the response you get from `WMSTileSource.createFrom(WMSEndpoint endpoint, WMSLayer layer)` after you have made a [call to the WMS server as mentioned in the wiki](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/WMS-Support).